# Couch DB returns empty array when passing date in multiple keys using startkey and end key

Tags: couchdb

My Query is:

```
SELECT SUM(hrs) from Work WHERE EmployeeNumber =? AND EmployeeName=? AND WorkDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

My KEY for couch DB

when I pass the other two strings like employee number and name I am getting data but when am adding date also I get empty array, but I see there is data for these dates.

I have tried sending dates as strings also but no result.

> ?startkey=["91444","Rick",[2018,2,4]]&endkey = ["91444","Rick",[2018,2,15]]

Comment: What is your `view` map function? Can you post it?

Comment: map: "function (doc) { if (doc.EmployeeNumber && doc.EmployeeName && doc.workDate) {  var date = doc.workDate.split('-');  var year = date[0]; var mon = date[1]; if(mon.charAt( 0 ) == '0') { mon = mon.slice( 1 ); } var day = date[2]; if(day.charAt( 0 ) == '0') { day = day.slice( 1 ); }   emit(doc.EmployeeNumber,doc.EmployeeName,[Number(year), Number(mon), Number(day)], doc.hrs); } }",
      reduce: "_sum"

Answer (score 0):

As posted in your comment, your view functions look like this:

```
map: "function (doc) { 
    if (doc.EmployeeNumber && doc.EmployeeName && doc.workDate) { 
        var date = doc.workDate.split('-'); 
        var year = date[0]; 
        var mon = date[1]; if(mon.charAt( 0 ) == '0') { mon = mon.slice( 1 ); } 
        var day = date[2]; if(day.charAt( 0 ) == '0') { day = day.slice( 1 ); } 
        emit(doc.EmployeeNumber,doc.EmployeeName,[Number(year), Number(mon), Number(day)], doc.hrs); 
    } 
}", 
reduce: "_sum"
```

In your map function you are emitting 4 things:

```
emit(
    doc.EmployeeNumber,
    doc.EmployeeName,
    [Number(year), Number(mon), Number(day)], 
    doc.hrs
);
```

As mentioned in [this documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html)

> The `emit()` function always takes two arguments: the first is `key`, and the second is `value`.

Therefore your map function doesn't look right.